# c# Linq webforms sum/group by issue for Dotnet.Highcharts

Tags: .net

I am struggling with an issue in c# where I want to group by and sum data in a List. Below is the code I am working with.

```
                        var segment = new List<object[]>();

                        foreach (var q in quarter)
                        {
                            var data = db.tbl_complaints_data
                                .Where(d => d.organisation_id == o.organisation_id && d.Service == site && d.Date.Month == q && d.Date.Year == year && d.Q1 != null)
                                .GroupBy(d => d.Q1)
                                .Select(d => new { q1 = d.Key, total = d.Count() });

                            foreach (var d in data)
                            {
                                string q1String = "Unknown";
                                switch (d.q1)
                                {
                                    case 1: q1String = "Stuff"; break;
                                    case 2: q1String = "Stuff 2"; break;
                                    case 3: q1String = "Stuff 3"; break;
                                    default: break;
                                }

                                segment.Add(new Object[] { q1String, d.total });
                            }
                        }

                        Render_PieChart(segment);
```

The data being passed in is spread over multiple months so this code executes for each month. Is it possible for me to edit segment at the end of the statement? I have tried .groupBy() but I can't get it to work.

So lets say we have Jan, Feb and March. Jan will run and data will be added to 'segment' like this:

```
stuff    1
stuff 2  2 
stuff 3  3
```

Then Feb will run and we get similar to above, the same will happen for March:

```
stuff    4
stuff 2  2
stuff 3  15
```

I want to then have the list 'segment' only contain the totals of the above, so when I render the chart it will only contain:

```
stuff    5
stuff 2  4
stuff 3  18
```

If this doesn't make sense, please let me know and I will try to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with a small redesign

```
                        var segment = new List<object[]>();
                        int yc1 = new int(); int ac1 = new int(); int ot1 = new int();

                        foreach (var q in quarter)
                        {
                            var data = db.tbl_complaints_data
                                .Where(d => d.organisation_id == o.organisation_id && d.Service == site && d.Date.Month == q && d.Date.Year == year && d.Q1 != null)
                                .GroupBy(d => d.Q1)
                                .Select(d => new { q1 = d.Key, total = d.Count() });

                            foreach (var d in data)
                            {
                                switch (d.q1)
                                {
                                    case 1: yc1 += d.total; break;
                                    case 2: ac1 += d.total; break;
                                    case 3: ot1 += d.total; break;
                                    default: break;
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (yc1 >= 1)
                            segment.Add(new Object[] { "Stuff", yc1 });

                        if (ac1 >= 1)
                            segment.Add(new Object[] { "Stuff 2", ac1 });

                        if (ot1 >= 1)
                            segment.Add(new Object[] { "Stuff 3", ot1 });

                        Render_PieChart(segment);
```